# KeyDB container problems in version 6.3.2 and later

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keydb

I have a Java application that uses a redundant KeyDB, load-balanced through HAProxy, where I store the elements with information to facilitate the business logic of my application. A few months ago, I pulled the Docker container for KeyDB, where I previously had version 6.0.18, and it was updated to version 6.3.2. However, shortly after this update, approximately a week after launching the containers, I started experiencing access issues with KeyDB. I continuously encounter the following error messages in my processes:

[image]

In the container logs, it appears that the primary node is unable to establish communication with the secondary node when the error occurs, and the connection timer expires:

[image]

From the HAProxy statistics page, it is observed that the nodes are up for a few seconds (about 30 continuously) and then they are marked as not operational for approximately 1 minute before coming back up, only to go down again intermittently for both nodes.

This is the information of the containers:

```
version: '3'
services:

  haproxy:
    image: haproxy:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./haproxy:/usr/local/etc/haproxy
    depends_on:
      - keydb-1
      - keydb-2
    restart: unless-stopped

  keydb-1:
    image: eqalpha/keydb

    command: keydb-server --port 6371 --requirepass rits --masterauth rits --notify-keyspace-events KEA --server-threads 8 --active-replica yes --replicaof keydb-2 6372
    ports:
      - "6371:6371"
    restart: unless-stopped

  keydb-2:
    image: eqalpha/keydb

    command: keydb-server --port 6372 --requirepass rits --masterauth rits --notify-keyspace-events KEA --server-threads 8 --active-replica yes --replicaof keydb-1 6371
    ports:
      - "6372:6372"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

I waited to see if later versions would change the situation by testing both 6.3.3 and 6.3.4, but the issue persists. I'm currently using version 6.0.18, which I initially had and with which I currently don't encounter any problems. However, I wouldn't like to remain stuck on a specific version of KeyDB in terms of future support for my application.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your YAML and post the output as text.

Comment: This is the correct indentation

Answer (score 0):

from the docs it seems as if you need to add a "--multi-master yes" to your keydb-server command

https://docs.keydb.dev/docs/multi-master/

Regards